# How to add preformatted text on text fields by clicking a button from another page

Tags: php, jquery, mailer

newbie here. Using php. So I have a button. When clicked will go to a contact page that I have already done. But I need to automatically put text into a text field for the message. All one has to do is click send as it is already formatted for them. How do I make the button automatically add text into the textfield(s)? I now realize it probably needs an onlick event or anything similar on the button that will post values on some text fields on the contact page being called. I hope I have given a better description of my problem. thanks guys.

Say this is my button:

```
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
```

on submit will go to contact page and fill in the values of some textfields I need preformatted.

here's my sample mailer script.

```
<?php 
//print_r($_POST);
if(isset($_POST['_save'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];

    if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($subject) || empty($message)) {
        if (empty($name))
            $error['name'] = "Please enter your Full Name";
        if (empty($email))
            $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid Email Address";
        if (empty($company))
            $error['company'] = "Please enter Your Company Name";
        if (empty($subject))
            $error['subject'] = "Please Write a Subject";

    }
    else { //if not empty

        $headers="From: {$email}\r\nReply-To: {$email}"; //create headers for email
        $content="Name: ".$name."\r\n\r\nCompany: ".$company."\r\n\r\nSubject: ".$subject."\r\n\r\nMessage: ".$message;
        mail('email@domain.com',$subject,$content,$headers); //mail the message;
        $success = "Thank you! You're email has been sent.";
        #done;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but if i understand correctly your requirement. then probably you want this.

1. You are at x page and page x has page has a button.
2. When you click a button you go to contact page.
3. You may passing some data using get or post method, you want to display that message on textarea of contact page.

If i am right and above scenario is correct then you can do like this:

```
<textarea name="message"><?php echo $_request['message']; ?></textarea>
```

`$_request` can get both post or get data.

thanks

Comment: This actually worked and lead me from one thing to another. In this case without using javascript I passed parameters onto the url and then  I added $message = $_GET['subject']; and for the message as well. then used <?php echo $subject ?> in the input field value and <?php echo $message ?> between the textarea tag. Works like a charm.

Comment: Oh crap, where are my manners. I have forgotten to say thanks to your answer. A few months late. But better late than never. Thanks a million @Humayoo.

Comment: Also, remember that `<?php echo $var ?>` can be replaced by the more readable and concise `<?= $var ?>`.

Answer (score 1):

on your previous page (eg. the input form for mail) use this;

```
<textarea name="message"> <?php echo 'the text message'; ?> </textarea>
```

or simply,

```
<textarea name="message"> the text message </textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks. I used your echo idea differently. <?php echo $subject ?>. see above. I actually learned from all your answers. cool.

Comment: Yes, I consider every suggestion and none of them will go to waste. You're post actually gave me the an idea to solve my own problem. I will click your post useful as it helped me realize more things i can do with the textarea tag. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As I read your question, I assume you have this flow in mind:

Probably a button,

```
<button type="submit" name="go_to_next"></button>
```

or

```
<input type="submit" name="go_to_next" value="Submit" />
```

that will redirect to contacts.php, where `<input>` fields are present

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="text" name="company" />
<input type="text" name="subject" />
<textarea cols="30" rows="10" name="message></textarea>
```

Now (just an assumption) that you want to have this fields default values when loaded, if it is, then all you have to do is set `<input value="" />`

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="Pepe Smith" />
<input type="text" name="email" value="pepesmith@mymail.com" />
<input type="text" name="company" value="My Company" />
<input type="text" name="subject" value="My Subject" />
<textarea cols="30" rows="10" name="message>My Message</textarea>
```

You can set dynamic values for this, but I'm not sure where you want those values to come from.

EDIT:

I created a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XeU3d/) of populating the fields by an onClick event in button.

Comment: I think you're close to it. Yes I do need that button. Sorry if I haven't made it quite clear, I was confused about it. Can we add an onclick event on the button to fill up the textfields in the page called by using javascript?

Comment: and yes I do think this is more of a javascript question as I now realize it. I need a button with an onclick event or similar that would post some values on some textfields on the contact page called.

Comment: I've seen the sample. I see the potential. It is quite interesting, that it got me thinking. what if we have the button redirect to contact page with url passing multiple parameters. contact page will then read off the url paramaters passed and get data from there to fill in the textfields. How can that be done?

Comment: Great! This is awesome. It actually solved it for me. I just added some stuff of my own. Splendid dude.

Comment: @wolverene Great I helped you at least in some way. Does this doesn't count as an accepted answer? :)

Comment: Uhm, actually I learned from all the suggestions. I'm trying to trace which one lead me to the final output I made. Because I was so confused of what I wanted, it turned out that the first post gave me the idea of passing url paramaters instead. Although your suggestion is brilliant, I can use it for another purpose. All the same thanks for that dude. But I will click the up arrow to make your post useful.